# Get the latest record for every group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wanted to do a select statement and get the latest record for every group of pos_code by row_num column. Please refer to the expected result in the below.

I have tried few functions like last_value and max() but these don't work. Please assist me on the select statement query.

Below is the view_table

```
 pos_code | dept_id | row_num
 10001    |    1    |    1
 10001    |    3    |    2
 10001    |    2    |    3
 10002    |    5    |    1
 10002    |    6    |    2
```

Expected result

```
 pos_code | dept_id | row_num
 10001    |    2    |    3
 10002    |    6    |    2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery in the `WHERE` clause which returns the maximum `row_num` for each `pos_code`:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where t.row_num = (select max(row_num) from tablename where pos_code = t.pos_code)
```

Comment: hi, do you mind to explain how does the select statement in the where clause works? Thanks for the answer btw.

Comment: The subquery returns the max row_num of each pos_code. So the row_num of every row of the table is compared to this max row_num. If they are equal then the row is returned if not then the row is filtered out. So for pos_code = 10001 the max row_num is 3 so only the row with row_num = 3 is returned.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick?

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        pos_code,
        dept_id,
        row_num,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pos_code ORDER BY row_num DESC) AS order_id
    FROM
        view_table)
SELECT
    pos_code,
    dept_id,
    row_num
FROM
    cte
WHERE
    order_id = 1;
```

Comment: hi, your answer also works but forpas's answer is more simple. Thanks btw.

Comment: no hard feelings... ;) both answers are valid, and they should perform very similarly.